# Didn't get an answer, should I cross post to cross validated

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I asked a question yesterday about having an example about maximum a posteriori estimation on math stack exchange but haven't got an answer yet. Since the subject is about Bayesian statistics, should I cross post this question to Cross Validated forum and try my luck there or what should I do?

Thnx for any advice :)

Comment: This post deals with the technicalities: [How do I move a post to another forum, like CV/stats?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/how-do-i-move-a-post-to-another-forum-like-cv-stats)

Comment: Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Step 1: check that your question is [on-topic at CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It would not hurt to browse their list of recent questions to see what is expected of question posters. (The expectations are not as low as at Math).

Comment: If you pass @40votes step 1, here's step 2: flag for moderator attention, and ask for the question to be migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outcome: the question was cross-posted, migrated, closed as duplicate and answered on stats.SE. (Should have been simply migrated.)